# Dynamic object reference

Tags: java, oop, object, dynamic, copy

I was trying to make an object arrayList and faced a problem: I  do not know how to dynamically create a new object from a particular ingredient / establish unique reference dynamically, so it point to a unique object, instead of printing out something Like this:

Coconut 366

Coconut 366

Coconut 366

// all coconuts in the list references to the last coconut, so no new unique Coconut container object

then I tried this:

allContainers.add( new Coconut() );

then access last item in the list and cast  object at current index of for loop iteration replacing an empty new Coconut(), however assignment of this does not work too..

Does anyone know to add unique reference on each method call of the same Object so values will be different as it will point to a different object?
Any suggestions how to solve this dilemma?

Thank you.

expansion of sample code:

```
ArrayList<TeaObjects> someTea = new ArrayList<TeaObjects>();
ArrayList<HealthyObjects> someHealth = new ArrayList<HealthyObjects>();

public void init {

someTea.add( new blackTea() );
someTea.add( new whiteTea() );
someTea.add( new greenTea() );
}


public void tea {

    // for loop checking for properties
    if (healthyTea) {


        // 1. Create a new instance dynamically of the lets say greenTea g1, where constructor is           empty

        // 2. add those properties to g1 =  (Cast ) (assign healthy properties)


        // 3. HealthyObjects.add(g1); // where g1 is dynamically created reference

    add to a list tea, so I want to achieve [new greenTea g1, new greenTea g2] to be in the list. I also want 



    }

}
```

Comment: Some sample would be useful

Comment: Maybe you can try a map? Not really sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, create a new instance each time.  Write a copy constructor:

```
public class Ingredient {
    private String name;

    public Ingredient(String name) { 
        this.name = name;
    }

    // copy constructor
    public Ingredient(Ingredient duplicate) {
        this.name = duplicate.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not help setting, as I need to instantiate a new object from the same class with a different reference.